# Lighthouse says "Links are not crawlable" on the "Skip to content" link

Tags: seo, lighthouse

When running a Lighthouse check on my site, I received the following error under **SEO**:

> **Links are not crawlable**
>
> Search engines may use `href` attributes on links to crawl websites.
> Ensure that the `href` attribute of anchor elements links to an
> appropriate destination, so more pages of the site can be discovered.
> [Learn More](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/links-crawlable)

The link that could not be crawled is `a#main-content`, which is the "Skip to main content" link.

This is the page's HTML:

```
<a href="#main-content" class="visually-hidden focusable"> Skip to main content </a>

..navbar..

<a id="main-content" tabindex="-1"></a>
```

As far as I know, this structure is completely fine and doesn't present any real problems for Google or any other search engine.  So what's the best way to address this error for this specific link?

I am trying to automate the Lighthouse reports in my CI pipeline, and I want to minimize the number of known errors.

Comment: Sounds like you need to find a better SEO evaluation tool.

Answer (score 4):

For this problem in Lighthouse 7.1.0, I use

```
<span id="main-content" tabindex="-1"></span>
```

and it works fine.

Comment: In other words you are using `<span>` tags instead of `<a>` tags?

Comment: yes. correct, i using <span> tags instead of <a> tags.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Lighthouse only complains if `<a>` is missing `href`, **even if that link is marked nofollow**, so one way to fix this is to point the "Skip to main content" link at something other than `<a>`.

Before:

```
<a id="main-content" tabindex="-1"></a>
```

After:

```
<main role="main" id="main-content">
```

Normally I would avoid workarounds to match the eccentricities of the evaluation tool, but in this case it's only one change for one link on a site with hundreds of pages.